# How can I detect a break with boost::asio::serial_port?

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I have a device which sends serial data in packets. Each packet is separated by a serial break (a low level on the serial line which lasts longer than a character).

How can I detect a break using `boost::asio::serial_port` ? There is a `send_break()` function, but I could not find information about receiving a break.

If I manually set the `PARMRK` flag and clear the `IGNBRK` and `BRKINT` flags in `c_iflag` using `tcsetattr`, the Linux serial driver converts a break into a `0xff 0x00 0x00` sequence which I can detect. However, the data can also contain this sequence so it is not ideal.

Is there a better way to detect a serial break using `boost::asio::serial_port` ?